# Chrome Kaspersky auto added eventlistener causing the captcha SESSION['security variable'] to change in the back ground

Tags: php, html, google-chrome-extension, captcha, kaspersky

I am developing an HTML user form where I am using a PHP captcha script:

```
<?php
session_start();


class CaptchaSecurityImages {

    var $font = 'php/monofont.ttf';

    function generateCode($characters) {
        /* list all possible characters, similar looking characters and vowels have been removed */
        $possible = '23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz';
        $code = '';
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $characters) { 
            $code .= substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
            $i++;
        }
        return $code;
    }

    function CaptchaSecurityImages($width='120',$height='40',$characters='6') {
        $code = $this->generateCode($characters);
        /* font size will be 75% of the image height */
        $font_size = $height * 0.75;
        $image = @imagecreate($width, $height) or die('Cannot initialize new GD image stream');
        /* set the colours */
        $background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
        $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 20, 40, 100);
        $noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 100, 120, 180);
        /* generate random dots in background */
        for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/3; $i++ ) {
            imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), 1, 1, $noise_color);
        }
        /* generate random lines in background */
        for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/150; $i++ ) {
            imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), $noise_color);
        }
        /* create textbox and add text */
        $textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $this->font, $code) or die('Error in imagettfbbox function');
        $x = ($width - $textbox[4])/2;
        $y = ($height - $textbox[5])/2;
        imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $this->font , $code) or die('Error in imagettftext function');
        /* output captcha image to browser */
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($image);
        imagedestroy($image);
        $_SESSION['security_code'] = $code;
    }

}

$width = isset($_GET['width']) ? $_GET['width'] : '120';
$height = isset($_GET['height']) ? $_GET['height'] : '40';
$characters = isset($_GET['characters']) && $_GET['characters'] > 1 ? $_GET['characters'] : '6';

$captcha = new CaptchaSecurityImages($width,$height,$characters);

?>
```

my form looks like:
[image]

it used to work like charm and all the sudden on form submission I am getting a frequent error that the user entered CAPTCHA doesn't match the picture,
Investigating further I found that: in chrome once I click any field in the form without typing the  $_SESSION['security_code'] value was changed on on its own on the server and ofcourse the photo was never updated, investigating further I found that there are some eventlisteners were set in chrome by my Kaspersky which seems they were the root cause of the problem as they were querying the Captcha photo link once I click on the form and start type in any field before submission (They look like that:-
[image]
, please note that my HTML file doesn't use any javascript that could have cause such event firing, as a double check I did try from another computer without Kaspersky and it works.

Now the question is how do I fix this for potential users that use kaspersky and wants to use my form?

Comment: Maybe `kaspersky` sends a unique user agent you could check for?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Log `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` somewhere and after loading see if you have your browser and another user agent.

Comment: just one user agent only  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36

Comment: very unusual behavior, I just checked and confirmed that Kaspersky chrome extension is disabled and been disabled by myself for a while, I don't know where the few event listeners in chrome came from !!!!???, if I try from different pc with no kaspersky I have no issues!!!!